# Fill in a Constant for a parameter mapping in an action in form processor

Tags: form-processor, action-provider

In form processor I'd like to map some constant value to a parameter in an action (e.g. a constant amount for a SEPA Mandate in the action "Create SEPA Mandate (Recurring)"). In the Section "Parameter Mapping" I can only map inputs and outputs of actions into the parameters, but not any constant value.

What's the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go is to use the action "Other: Set Value". Form Processor only handles objects not strings themselves.

By setting a condition on that action, values can be set conditionally even.

Even better, by using action "Other: Map Value" one can map values of parameters to other values obtaining conditioned constants in a new parameter. The mapping is given as a JSON dictionary e.g. `{ "A": "10", "B" : "20" }`.